Is there a way to prevent user to redirect if there is an error?
I have a simple signup form which works perfectly but I noticed when there is an error it still redirects to the homepage.
import { Loader, Lock, Mail, User } from "lucide-react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Input from "../components/Input";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import PasswordStrengthMeter from "../components/PasswordStrengthMete";
import { useAuthStore } from "../store/auth.store";

export const SignUpPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const { signup, error, isLoading } = useAuthStore();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signup(email, password, name);
     if(!error){
      navigate("/");
     }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


//authStore.jsx
import { create } from "zustand";

const API_URI = "http://localhost:3001/api/auth";
export const useAuthStore = create((set) => ({
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isCheckingAuth: false,
  message: null,
  user: null,

  signup: async (email, password, name) => {
    set({ isLoading: true, error: null });
    try {
      const options = {
        credentials: "include",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password, name }),
      };

      const response = await fetch(`${API_URI}/signup`, options);
      console.log(response);

      if (!response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        throw new Error(data.message);
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      set({ user: data.user, isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      set({
        error: error.message || "Error signing up",
        isLoading: false,
      });
    }
  },



When I try to go back the browser and hit the button submit it will now prevent it from redirecting because the error is now being stored in the variable. I believe logic is true first before the error variable is stored. that's why! Is there a better way to do it? or how does the logic work?

Have you checked what the value of error in the try is? Assuming it's not empty, because I don't see the error variable defined anywhere within the try, you have to verify that. Next up, if signup is actually throwing an error, the if shouldn't even run, so you should make sure that signup throws an actual error and is not returning a json with an error message. I would  store the result of the signup in a variable and console.log it or use a debugger to view it.

handleSignUp has a stale closure over the error value. If you want to read the error then signup should return it to the caller so it can be appropriately acted on. The alternative is to move the error checking and redirect into a useEffect hook that runs later and can react to the error value updating. Do either of these make sense? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so we can see what it's doing?

@GABRIELRGARCIA-AVILES I update and icluded the files. I use Zustand

@DrewReese. can read again I updated my question

I think the problem is the logic is true while the error occurred while rerendering

Your catch method in the signup sets a value rather than throwing an error. I think that might be the problem.

handleSignUp has a stale closure over the error value returned by the useAuthStore hook.
I would suggest updating the signup handler to throw errors out for callers to catch and handle. If no errors/exceptions are thrown then assume success, otherwise, catch and handle them appropriately.
Example:
signup: async (email, password, name) => {
  set({ isLoading: true, error: null });
  try {
    const options = {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password, name }),
    };

    const response = await fetch(`${API_URI}/signup`, options);
    const data = await response.json();

    set({ user: data.user, isAuthenticated: true, isLoading: false });

    // Return data to caller
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    set({
      error: error.message || "Error signing up",
      isLoading: false,
    });

    // Re-throw error for caller
    throw error;
  }
},

const { signup, error, isLoading } = useAuthStore();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleSignUp = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    await signup(email, password, name);
    // const data = await signup(email, password, name);

    // Success, navigate to home
    navigate("/");
  } catch (error) {
    // Failure, handle error
    console.log(error);
  }
};


I got it Guys, thanks for the help. I added a return value for the signup. The function itself returns 1 and for the catch block return 0
here is the logic:
//store the return value to reference the redirection logic
 const methodFetch = await signup(email, password, name);
      if (methodFetch === 1) {
        navigate("/verify-email");
      }


// authStore.jsx Files
 signup: async (email, password, name) => {
set({ isLoading: true, error: null });
try {
   //....logic
} catch (error) {
  set({
    //....logic
  });

  return 0; // return 0 if error
}

return 1; //success return 1

},
I don't know if this is the right way to do it. but it works now! haha

Cross check data type of Error variable

String error: "Text"

if (!error) { 
 // do something
}


Object error: { message: "Text" }

if (Object.keys(error).length === 0) { 
 // do something
}


Array ( Error: [] or [{status: "Text"}])

if (Object.keys(error).length === 0) { 
 // do something
}

